# How to generate a line break in Django template

Tags: html, django-templates, newline

I want to give default value to a textarea. The code is something like this:

```
<textarea>{{userSetting.list | join:"NEWLINE"}}</textarea>
```

where `userSetting.list` is a string list, each item of whom is expected to show in one line.

`textarea` takes the content between the tags as the default value, preserving its line breaks and not interpreting any HTML tags (which means `<br>`,`\n` won't work).

I have found a solution: `{{userSetting.list | join:" " | wordwrap:0}}` (there is no whitespace in the list). But obviously it is NOT a good one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Chris didn't come and collect the credit, I have to answer my question myself. (But still thanks him for pointing to [the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621918/how-to-generate-a-line-break-in-django-template/2630126#2630126))

The HTML entity `&#10;` stands for a NEWLINE character, and won't be interpreted in Django template. So this will work:

```
<textarea>{{userSetting.list | join:"&#10;"}}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the accepted answer did not work for me, but this did:

```
<div>{{ list|join:'<br>' }}</div>
```

Docs reference for `join`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#join

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{{userSetting.list | join:"&#10;"}}` if 
 and `\n` won't work. Let me know how you get on...

:P

Comment: `&vbCrLf` is not a valid HTML entity. But thanks for pointing to the right direction: `{{userSetting.list | join:"&#10;"}}` works. Would you please modify your answer so that I can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks Iamamac,I need newlines in <textarea>. YOu have solved my problem :)

Comment: @iamamac I'm back 8 years later to say you're welcome, and I updated my answer haha :P

Answer (score 0):

A textarea in HTML does respect newlines. Does this not escape the \n:

```
<textarea>{{userSetting.list | join:"\n"}}</textarea>
```

I'm thinking that it should turn the \n into a newline character, so your source looks like this:

```
<textarea>Setting 1
Setting 2
Setting 3</textarea>
```

This would work if it did, but it may not convert `\n` correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that. It's just I didn't know how to insert  a newline character in Django template. (And Chris helped me find it out)